# Email attachment file names are removed with AT00001

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, smtplib

Sending mail with multiple attachments is removing attachment file names. The attachment name is changed to ATT00001.xlsx. As per following link, 'body' section added before attachment, but no luck.

```
https://exchange-server-guide.blogspot.com/2015/11/att00001.txt-file-fix-email-attachment-issue.html
```

For reference, sharing the following code snippet. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
ctype = content_type
maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['To'] = 'abc@sample.com'
msg['From'] = sender
smtp_client = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_host + ':' + smtp_port)
smtp_client.starttls()
smtp_client.login(sender, smtp_login_password)
body_part = MIMEText(body, 'plain')
msg.attach(body_part)
for file_path in file_paths :
    temp_arr = file_path.split('/')
    file_name = temp_arr[len(temp_arr) - 1]
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
    fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
    attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
    attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encode_base64(attachment)
    msg.attach(attachment)
smtp_client.sendmail(sender, 'abc@sample.com', msg.as_string())
smtp_client.quit()
```

Comment: There are a lot of missing `import`s and undeclared variables here. The SMTP sending part isn't really necessary (and in properly modular code should not be tangled with the message composition code). Look at the guidance for providing a [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the `Content-Disposition:` to the multipart container. You should add it to each individual body part.

Change this:

```py
for file_path in file_paths :
    temp_arr = file_path.split('/')
    file_name = temp_arr[len(temp_arr) - 1]
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
    fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
    attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
    attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    encode_base64(attachment)
    msg.attach(attachment)
```

to something like

```py
for file_path in file_paths:
    file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
    attachment = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as fp:
        attachment.set_payload(fp.read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
    encode_base64(attachment)
    msg.attach(attachment)
```

where I also took the liberty to switch to using a context manager (`with` statement).  I also simplified the file name extraction.

Comment: Demo: broken https://ideone.com/aPwmBN fixed https://ideone.com/b7EZqo